# Facebook like Video uploader plugins

Tags: video, plugins, upload

I want that through my web page user could upload audio/video files & it will display exactly like in Facebook.

I searched for such type of AJAX plugin but failed to got..

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried jQuery plugin

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/